Chrome Crashing on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Various Errors After Update
I recently updated Google Chrome to the latest version, specifically Version 127.0.6533.119 (Official Build) (64-bit), on my system running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Since the update, Chrome has been consistently crashing, accompanied by a series of error messages that I've listed below. These crashes occur randomly during usage, making it difficult to pinpoint a specific action or website that triggers them.
Error messages observed include:

[22685:22685:0819/211325.365470:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to
call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path=
/org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported:
This method is not implemented Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK
delegate for CPU.
[22728:22728:0819/211329.380335:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)]
GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times! Fontconfig error:
Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)

Multiple instances of

[22685:22685:0819/211335.530878:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(722)]
Message 1 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost Attempting to
use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph
that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#58 is a dynamic-sized tensor).
[22728:22728:0819/211414.143597:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)]
GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
[0819/211417.162379:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not
found Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Multiple instances of

[8092:8092:0819/215718.672681:ERROR:atom_cache.cc(229)] Add
chromium/x-source-url to kAtomsToCache
[0819/215737.134438:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not
found Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

I have searched through various forums and documentation but haven't found a solution that directly addresses this combination of errors or the specific version of Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I've tried basic troubleshooting steps such as clearing cache, disabling extensions, and checking for conflicting applications, but the issue persists.
Given the complexity and variety of errors, I'm seeking guidance from the community on how to approach resolving these crashes. Any insights into what might be causing these errors or steps to diagnose further would be greatly appreciated.

Go to Chrome settings, System, disable Use graphic acceleration when available and restart and test it. If It works I will write an answer.

No, disabling graphics acceleration didn't solve the issue; my Chrome is still crashing every few minutes. :(
[6895:6895:0820/195031.360014:ERROR:atom_cache.cc(229)] Add chromium/x-source-url to kAtomsToCache [0820/195041.838432:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Yes sudo apt --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable

Just updated now and facing the same crashes with the same errors as well. And can't rollback as apt doesn't have the previous version anymore

I suggest you two to report thr problem to chrome the link I have is for EU https://support.google.com/chrome/threads?hl=en&thread_filter=%28category%3Achrome_crashes%29&sjid=9207116293462895605-EU

I have reported this to Google Chrome Help now also...
